# How to simulate a mecanum wheel in Gazebo?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello.

All my technical problems are hopefully behind me. I can now address core simulation questions.

The robot I'm working on (youBot) is equipped with "mecanum wheels". I did not this kind of wheel before. They allow the mobile platform to move in any direction.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mecanum_wheel

http://lego.cuusoo.com/ideas/view/39585

The URDF files I found have implemented this part with simple wheels and casters. This is far from the real moves of the youBot, which "glides" on the ground.

Any idea of how to simulate this kind of wheels with a simplified model? (I guess that simulating the full dynamics of the wheel will be too heavy )

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4078/how-to-simulate-a-mecanum-wheel-in-gazebo?/) by [Arn-O](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/416/arn-o/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 316 on 2013-08-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Just a thought, for this robot it may be easier to model the motion of the entire robot instead of modeling the individual wheel. One path could be to use a plugin that accepts twist messages and applies them to the robot base. An example of this is the [Planar Move Plugin](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/ROS_Motor_and_Sensor_Plugins#Planar_Move_Plugin).

In two dimension (i.e. stage) this might have been called the holonomic plugin.

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/43/sl-remy/) with karma: 319 on 2013-08-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arn-O](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/416/arn-o/) on 2013-08-07**:
OK, thanks, I will have a look at this option.

**Comment by [Arn-O](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/416/arn-o/) on 2013-09-19**:
Finally very close to the real movement, even if the render is not realistic. I had to replace the real wheels by spheres.

**Comment by [arennuit](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/958/arennuit/) on 2014-09-04**:
Hello Arn-O, I am currently facing the same simulation pb for another robot. Can you give some more details on how you simulated the mecanum wheels for your youbot? Thanks ;)